# apply variable on views in the template

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, django, tweak

A part of my html code

```
var marker;

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mymap"), myOptions);
    getMapMetadata([]);

    // setInterval(function(){ getMapMetadata([]); }, 3000);
}


function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {

    // alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
    var contentString = '<b>' + label + '</b><br>' + html;
    var image;
    image = 'static/img/30.png';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: label,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
    });
    marker.myname = label;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;
}

function getMapMetadata(ids) {

    $.get("{% url 'app01:cate' %}", { ids: [] }, function(data, status) {
                console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data) + "\nStatus: " + status);
                var metadata;
                var i;
                //for(var i=0;  i<data.length; i++)
                metadata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                for (i = 0; i < metadata.length; i++) {
                    console.log("item: " + metadata[i].x);
                    marker = createMarker(new google.maps.LatL ng(metadata[i].x, metadata[i].y), metadata[i].id + "", JSON.stringify(metadata[i]));
```

A part of views

```
uavs = [Map.objects.get(pk=str(i)) for i in range(1, NUAVs+1)]
```

I want to add this variable which contains the variation of value of 2 points, to the marker in my template

Answer (score 0):

What does the rest of your `views` look like?

Read the docs on making views, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/) and some [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/)

You would pass the `uavs` variable from the view to the template, and access it using `"{{uavs}}"`

Comment: {% for u in uavs %}
x={{u.x}}
y={{u.y}}
 marker=createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(metadata[i].x,metadata[i].y),metadata[i].id+"",JSON.stringify(metadata[i]));
{% endfor%}
but it does not work